# Inserting an HTML section ID in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

How do I set an html section id depending on some condition using AngularJs? 
I've tried `"<section ng-attr-id="{'blue' : character.name=='John', 'pink' : character.name=='Jenny'}">` but it's not working.

Comment: How do I set section id depending on some condition? I've tried 
 "<section ng-attr-id="{'blue' : character.name=='John', 'pink' : character.name=='Jenny'}">. It's not working.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using inside your `ng-attr-id` is not correct. Define some function which takes the name and returns the id inside your controller and expose it on the `$scope`, e.g.

```
$scope.getIdForName = function (name) {
  if (name == 'John') {
    return 'blue';
  else if (name == 'Jenny') {
    return 'pink';
  }
}
```

Then you can do the following in your template:

```
<section ng-attr-id="{{getIdForName(character.name)}}">
```